# Removing duplicates from a BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, duplicates, lodash, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I've got an angular component which gets a BehaviorSubject array of things as input, which can be changed externally. The component should display this array of things and update the component view depending on what is in the array. The component also subscribes to changes on the BehaviorSubject so that it should specifically select the 'enabled' thing out of the array automatically. I also want to check if there are duplicates in this array and remove it automatically. I've tried calling .next() in the subscribe after finding duplicates but even though the array of things looks correct, the view doesn't reflect correctly. It shows the array without removing the duplicates. Don't know if my approach correct or not? What am I doing wrong?

I've got this in my ngOnInit() function:

```
this.things$.subscribe(things => {
  const uniqueThings = _.uniqBy(things,'name');
  if (uniqueThings.length !== things.length) {
    this.things$.next([...uniqueThings]);
  } else {
    this.selectEnabledThing(things.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: The component input: @Input() things$: BehaviorSubject<Array<Thing>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

Comment: `this.things$.pipe(map(things => _.uniqBy(things, 'name'))).subscribe(...);`

Comment: @Siri0S I've tried that now. So in the subscribe I would get the unique things but the component view shows all the things. How do I make the view match up with whats in the array? Thought this would just work.

Comment: You should assign the observable to a variable e.g.: `const thingsToShow$ = this.things$.pipe(map(things => _.uniqBy(things, 'name')))`. And then in your html it should be something like: `<div *ngFor="let thing of thingsToShow$ | async">`

Comment: But I actually need it to subscribe to the array having both unique things and the 'enabled' thing selected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you want your view to only show the unique things? Maybe you should post some more code to show what it is exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm expecting the duplicate thing with name ('test2') to be removed and at the same time the view should highlight the enabled thing (iterating over all the things until it finds the enabled thing). Things = [
    {
        name: 'test1',
        enabled: true
    },
    {
        name: 'test2',
        enabled: false
    },
    {
        name: 'test2',
        enabled: false
    }
]

Comment: I'm currently using my things$ behaviorsubject in the view using the async pipe. Was hoping to subscribe by removing duplicates and updating the array using the next function inside the subscription... and when it comes back into that subscription and no duplicates are found.. it should just select the enabled task.

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hilxvu) is a stackblitz demo that shows how to do it (if i understand it correctly).